# Windows 7 Professional to Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) installed and am planning on upgrading it to Windows 7 Professional (64-bit).

I would like to know if it is possible, however, to revert back to Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) once I have installed Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be able to, you'd have to do a clean install.  Can't think why you'd want to go back though, Professional only adds features.

Comment: I thought the same; the reason for wanting to go back is because I am a mature student and thus have access to free Microsoft products courtesy of Microsoft/MSDN.  A friend of mine a couple of years ago mentioned that he installed Windows 7 Professional, but told me that it was only a trial version and the functionality of it was limited, which is my only concern.

Comment: As far as I know, if you install anything from MSDN, it's the full copy, not a trial version.  I'm sure it would tell you while installing it though, so you can make the decision at that point.

Comment: That's what I thought too - maybe my friend had installed something totally different!  Thanks for your help, Nick.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I fine this on another site:

"here is a “simple” hack which allows you to embed the downgrade procedure in Windows 7.

Click Start.
In the Search Box, type regedit and press Enter.
Navigate to this registry key: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ Microsoft\ Windows NT\CurrentVersion

In the right pane, click EditionID and ProductName and give them the value which corresponds to a lower Windows 7 edition. Here is an example:

Windows 7 Home Premium (downgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Home Premium)

EditionID: HomePremium

ProductName: Windows 7 HomePremium

Start your Windows 7 installation by inserting your Windows 7 Disc.
Now, Select Upgrade as type of installation. Follow the instruction on the screen.
Reactivate your operating system. "

Attention:
Text "HomeEdition" and "HomePremium" must be without spaces!!!

Comment: Where is the source from this? Have you tried it yourself, even in just a virtual machine? There are HUNDREDS of locations that Windows stores what edition it is